# How to create an alias that counts Ws, Ls, and Ds to create a record

Tags: sql

I have a table with sports results with a column labeled 'Result' where the values in that column are either W, L, or D. I would like to create an alias column that will quickly count the Ws, Ls, and Ds from the whole table in that columns and display it as 'Count W-Count L-Count D'.

I'm very new to SQL and I haven't figured this specific of a request out, nor can I find the correct search terms in Google to discover a video or forum result for the situation I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the values in separate *columns*, use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when result = 'W' then 1 else 0 end) as w_cnt,
       sum(case when result = 'L' then 1 else 0 end) as l_cnt,
       sum(case when result = 'T' then 1 else 0 end) as t_cnt
from t;
```

Comment: I'm about 5 days late to respond to you, but what you provided is actually as close to what I was looking for as I think is possible. This provides me the capability to see win-loss records by teams (aka GROUP BY teams) where in the other option it would only let me see my absolute total of wins and losses.

Answer (score 0):

Best option go for group by

```
   Select result, count(*) from table
   where column IN ('W' , 'L' , 'D' ) 
  group by result
```

Comment: Select Result, count(*) from table
   where Result IN ('W' , 'L' , 'D') 
  group by Result
I have updated the table in the actual query, but I haven't in my reply because it has identifiable information. I'm getting the following error: 'Error converting data type varchar to float.' Do I need to modify my column type?

Comment: What is your result type? Yes, its related to data type.

Comment: My column 'Result' is currently set at varchar(50)

Comment: I made the change to:
Select Result, count(*) from table
   where Result IN "W" , "L" , "D") 
  group by Result
Incorrect syntax near 'W'.

Comment: Sorry my bad single qoutes is for data and double qoutes is for column names. It should have worked with single qoutes. Can you share the data sample or else remove the where clause and then run the same

Comment: Sure, I can share it, but I don't know the best way to do that. I'm a novice to the website, and programming. I know how to get the information, but what the best way to display/share it.

Comment: I sincerely apologize, I used the wrong column name, and your first solution worked. Again I apologize for the waste of time, I'll do better next time. Thank you very much for your help. Removing the WHERE clause immediately showed me my error.

Comment: No problem. I would suggest you to start learning basics of sql online.